# Refactor an Object that expects one thing to expect many things

Tags: go, refactoring

I am working on updating a Go codebase. Our company has a central data store, fictionally called DataStore, that you can publish to or read from various datasets or schemas. Our particular code base has some code that couples a specific dataset/schema to a DataStore implementation. I need to refactor this code to enable writing to an additional (and potentially many more) datasets.

In the code below, `dataStoreSchema` represents a single schema, like "Customers" data. But I have other schemas like "Orders", or whatever that have different fields that I would like to write to.

`transformEvent` takes data that would be passed to `DataStore` and does some logic to create the `dataStoreSchema` object which then gets written to the actual DataStore in the cloud.

I want to write to potentially *any* schema on the data store, not just the one that this implementation is coupled to.

```
type Parameters struct {
    SchemaName              string
    Host                    string
    Secret                  string
}

type DataStore struct {
    params                *Parameters
    url                   string
    request               *http.Client
}

// imagine this defines an Order, but other schemas might be for Customer
type dataStoreSchema struct {
    eventUrl string `json:"url"`
    objectID string `json:"object_id"`
}

func New(parameters) (*DataStore, error) {
    // implementation

    return &stream, nil
}

// takes input and converts it into a schema object that can be written to the datastore
func (ds *DataStore) transformEvent(...) dataStoreSchema {

    // .... implementation

    return dataStoreSchema{
        eventUrl: url,
        objectID: objectId,
    }
}

func (ds *DataStore) writeEvents(...) error {

    // .... implementation
    payload := ds.transformEvent(event)
        

    ds.produce(payload)
}

func (ds *DataStore) produce(msg []events) {
        ds.WriteToDatastore(msg)
}
```

Right now the behavior is this

```
myDatasetClient := DataStore.New(params)
myDatasetClient.write(<-messages chan)
```

But I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
myDatasetClient1 := DataStore.New(params{schema1, transformEvent1})
myDatasetClient2 := DataStore.New(params{schema2, transformEvent2})
myDatasetClient3 := DataStore.New(params{schema3, transformEvent3})
```

Or whatever makes the most sense in Go terms

Comment: I  don't think you gave enough information to answer this question. For instance: what is `logicFunc`? What do you expect to happen when you do that? Does the schema determine the dataset? If so, a simple map would solve this.

Comment: hopefully my changes help clarify the issue and desired outcome

Comment: Please also add some type information. Looks like `write` gets a channel, but of what type? Or do you want to parameterize that as well?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your current implementation is tightly coupled to a specific schema through the `dataStoreSchema` struct and the `transformEvent` method. The `transformEvent` method takes an input and converts it into a `dataStoreSchema` object, which then gets written to the DataStore.

You want to write to potentially any schema on the data store, not just the one that the current implementation is coupled to.

```golang
myDatasetClient1 := DataStore.New(params{schema1, transformEvent1})
myDatasetClient2 := DataStore.New(params{schema2, transformEvent2})
myDatasetClient3 := DataStore.New(params{schema3, transformEvent3})
```

Meaning: you want to create different `DataStore` clients, each associated with a different schema and a corresponding transformation function (`transformEvent1`, `transformEvent2`, `transformEvent3`).
That should mean to decouple the transformation logic from the `DataStore` struct, allowing for handling different schemas with different transformation functions.

You could use an interface for different schema transformations and modifying the `Parameters` and `DataStore` structs:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

// Define a Transformer function type that takes an event of type E and returns a schema of type S
type Transformer[E any, S any] func(event E) S

type Parameters[E any, S any] struct {
    SchemaName  string
    Host        string
    Secret      string
    TransformFn Transformer[E, S]
}

type DataStore[E any, S any] struct {
    params  *Parameters[E, S]
    url     string
    request *http.Client
}

// Define structs for different schemas and events
type OrderSchema struct {
    eventUrl string `json:"url"`
    objectID string `json:"object_id"`
    // other fields
}

type OrderEvent struct {
    // fields
}

type CustomerSchema struct {
    eventUrl string `json:"url"`
    objectID string `json:"object_id"`
    // other fields
}

type CustomerEvent struct {
    // fields
}

// New creates a new DataStore
func New[E any, S any](params Parameters[E, S]) (*DataStore[E, S], error) {
    // implementation
    return &DataStore[E, S]{params: &params}, nil
}

func (ds *DataStore[E, S]) transformEvent(event E) S {
    return ds.params.TransformFn(event)
}

// rest of the code remains the same

// Usage:
func main() {
    orderTransformFn := func(event OrderEvent) OrderSchema {
        // implementation for Order schema
    }

    customerTransformFn := func(event CustomerEvent) CustomerSchema {
        // implementation for Customer schema
    }

    myDatasetClient1, _ := New[OrderEvent, OrderSchema](Parameters[OrderEvent, OrderSchema]{SchemaName: "schema1", TransformFn: orderTransformFn})
    myDatasetClient2, _ := New[CustomerEvent, CustomerSchema](Parameters[CustomerEvent, CustomerSchema]{SchemaName: "schema2", TransformFn: customerTransformFn})
    // ...
}
```

The Transformer function type is now parameterized with two type parameters: `E` for the event type and `S` for the schema type.
The Parameters and DataStore structs are also parameterized with the same two type parameters `E` and `S`.
The transformEvent method of DataStore now accepts an event of type `E` and returns a schema of type `S`.

To handle more schemas, you would define new function types or instances conforming to the `Transformer` function signature, along with the corresponding event and schema structs. You would not be defining new structs that implement a `Transformer` interface since `Transformer` is now a function type, not an interface.
So, you can extend the codebase to handle more schemas by defining new [transformation functions](https://go.dev/blog/why-generics#what-generics-can-bring-to-go) and schema structs, without modifying the existing `DataStore` implementation.